# Why do internal combustion engines only burn to carbon monoxide, not dioxide?

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion

Why don't diesel and regular car engines burn all the way to $\ce{CO2}$?

Comment: Most of the carbon-oxygen stuff coming out is CO2.  Some isn't, because of detailed balance of the chemistry, inhomogeneous conditions in the piston, etc.

Comment: Seems like another question easily answered with very minor googling.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is sort of covered by [What really happens atomically in an explosion?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15995/what-really-happens-atomically-in-an-explosion) because the burning of the fuel air mixture is basically an explosion. The point is that there isn't a nice simple answer because the reaction is fearsomely complex.

Actually most of the fuel does burn to carbon dioxide. The proportion of carbon monoxide is quite small. In a normally tuned engine there is enough oxygen to burn all the fuel to carbon dioxide but the fuel/air mixture isn't in the cylinder long enough for the reaction to go to completion. You probably know that all modern cars are fitted with [catalytic convertors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalytic_converter), and what they do is to complete the reaction as the exhaust gases pass through them.

Comment: But why not run with excess air to make sure it is all burned? This is especially true with Diesel engines which pump out pure carbon

Comment: @DirkBruere: Getting the maximum engine efficiency, i.e. the combination of good mpg with high power, is something of a black art as lots and lots of parameters are involved. An obvious parameter is the fuel/air mixture, and it turns out that the optimal fuel/air ratio results in some carbon monoxide being left in the exhaust gases.

Comment: Well, yes. That was my question, sort of. If we get more energy by burning to CO2 why do we deliberately stop short of that? What are we optimizing?

Comment: @DirkBruere: Generally, if you run lean (high air/fuel) you decrease power and the engine runs hotter so it generates more oxides of nitrogen. I think the mpg are slightly better with a leaner mixture, but the power falls. Exactly why the currently used ratio is considered optimal I don't know. I'm sure a Google would find articles on the subject.

Comment: This is why I posted it in physics - it's not really a chemistry question. Those who voted to move it did not seem to understand.